# Проблема с выводом на экране

Tags: c#

Такой код, но мне нужно чтобы он выводил так:

> a aa
>   b ab
>   c ac
>   a ba
>   b bb
>   c bc
>   и т.д.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string st = "abc";
            for (int a = 0; a < st.Length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < st.Length; b++)
                {
                    string s1 = st[a].ToString();
                    string s2 = st[a].ToString() + st[b].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(s1 + " " + s2);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

никак не могу понять где причина..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
string s1 = st[b].ToString();
```

Единственное отличие этого кода от вашего: индекс `a` заменен на `b`.

Comment: проблему решил, все оказалось просто проще некуда